# Dry Well Against Foundation

Tags: drainage, slab, downspout

I live in a house with a slab foundation. The soil is red clay. One of the downspouts outputs 8 inches above the ground into a small flower bed and walkway. When it rains, a divot is formed into the mulch and runs over the walkway.

The flower bed is about 4x4 feet. I was thinking of digging down 4-5 feet, lay in landscaping fabric, and filling the hole with crushed stone to help with drainage. Is this safe for the foundation?
I want to avoid digging under the walkway since it's a new house and landscape.

Comment: There are quite a few different downspout diverters so the water does not drop heavy onto one spot.  From plastic pads to roll up tubing to extensions to carry the water away from the house.  Usually want water away from the house, not draining right beside it.  Rain barrels are another idea if you want to collect the water for the flowers.

Comment: HOA doesn't allow rain barrels. I have plastic pads but they don't fit in the space and still will erode away the walkway. I guess the only other option is under ground tubing

Comment: If it were me, I'd tell the HOA that they'll be on the hook for foundation repair since they won't allow you to install simple water diversion methods, but that's an ugly, uphill battle with a bunch o' busy bodies who have nothing better to do with their lives than meddle in other's business. What's this walkway made of that water is going to erode it that quickly? If you put an elbow on the downspout and another length of downspout, the water won't _fall_ into the flowers, it will _flow_ out the end. Still may cause issues, but it won't dig a hole.